# Extracting a substring where delimiter is "..."

Tags: vba, excel

I need to divide a string into two parts on the basis of a delimiter but the problem is my delimiter consists of multiple delimiters.

For example:
String ->  `7...5`
I need to extract 7 and 5 but the split function returns the same string as variant.

Any simple way to do this? I don't want to use RegExp.

```
Function f1(Value As String) As Boolean
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim length As Integer
    Dim c As Variant
    Dim c1 As Variant

    flag = True

    If IsNumeric(Value) = False Then
        flag = False
    End If

     c = Split(Value, ":")
     If UBound(c) < 1 Then
        c = Split(Value, "...") 'Here split does not divide it into array
     End If

Function f()
      If f1(Cells(5,10).Value) = False Then
      ' Do something      
      End If
End Function
```

Comment: There are so many possibilities. `1` Will the De-limiters be of same length always? `2` Will the numbers at the end and beginning always be of 1 digit?

Comment: 1) yes, we can assume delimiter will be of same length
2) NO, I have taken this as an example

Comment: Will they always be DOTS or it can be anything? Also will they always be non numeric?

Comment: Please update the question with few actual examples

Comment: there will be DOTS only as delimiters, There can be non numeric numbers as well. Example 
abcdeee...fghthi. Once we are able to extract the strings then I can do my processing or whatever I want

Comment: If you know the length and there will only be dots then you can use them as delimiters. For example `Split("7...5","...")`

Comment: I tried this but VB returned the exact same string As variant

Comment: Posted and answer... You may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with string "...". As, it has a predifined ASCII code of 0133. For parsing the string, i have specified the character code and used Chr function to convert it into character.

```
c = Split(ValueString,Chr(0133)) 'after this c contains two arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1** If you **KNOW** the length and there will only be dots then you can use them as delimiters. For example `Split("7...5","...")`

Example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sDelim As String, sTest As String

    sTest = "7...5"
    sDelim = "..."

    Debug.Print Split(sTest, sDelim)(0)
    Debug.Print Split(sTest, sDelim)(1)
End Sub
```

**Way 2** If you **DON'T KNOW** the length and there will only be dots then use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sDelim As String, sTest As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    sTest = "7...5"

    '~~> other test Scenarios
    'sTest = "75.....56"
    'sTest = "734.......5"
    'sTest = "7.......5567"

    For i = 1 To Len(sTest)
        If Mid(sTest, i, 1) = "." Then
            Debug.Print "The First Number is " & Left(sTest, i - 1)
            j = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    For i = j To Len(sTest)
        If Mid(sTest, i, 1) <> "." Then
            Debug.Print "The Second Number is " & _
            Right(sTest, Len(sTest) - (i - 1))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the meaning of "(0)" in Debug.Print Split(sTest, sDelim)(0)

Comment: Split, breaks the string into an array. When you don't specify dimensions of an array, then the first element of the array is accessed using `0`. For example `Ar(0)`. I would recommend reading about arrays :)

Comment: i did not know we can access the variant this way.
i tried your method here is what i found. I wrote 
 c1 = Split(Value, "...")(0) where value is 7...0 and after this c1 only contains 7...0 , something wrong on my part or you haven't tested your code ?

Comment: @JasmeetNarula: All the code that I post is TRIED & TESTED. But sometimes I am unable to do so for some reason, and usually say so if this is the case. So yes, I tested the above code before posting. And Hence, I guess you are doing something wrong...

Comment: OK. Can you please help me identify what i'm doing wrong ?For checking,  I'm just applying watch points on c1 and getting a single string/array of "7...0"

Comment: Update your question with the exact code that you are using. Copy the code from your vba editor and paste it in the above quesiton.

Comment: i have uploaded my code and something i noticed when i put directly a string like "7...0" in the split function , everything start working. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong ? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Show me the routine which passes th value of `Value` to that function

Comment: What is the value in the cell `Cells(5,10).Value`?

Comment: After the line `c = Split(Value, "...")`, if you type `msgbox c(0)` and `msgbox c(1)`. What do you get?

Comment: msgbox c(0) gives me 7...0 and msgbox c(1) gives me an error because index does not exist

Comment: Ok before the line `c = Split(Value, "...")`, type this `Msgbox len(Value)`. What do you get?

Comment: it gave me 3 and now I'm unabale to understand how vb is working with strings

Comment: And that is where your problem is :) It should have given you `5` Step though the code and check

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for helping me in debugging this but now added my msg box at top of my function but still got 3. I did change  formatting of cells for stopping excel to convert my string into date format. Anything related to this ?

Comment: Yup that could be it. What happens when you change the line `If f1(Cells(5,10).Value) = False Then` to `If f1(Cells(5,10).Text) = False Then`

Comment: No luck but adding my code here , can you take a look ? I read somewhere on stack overflow only. 
//Code for formatting
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In Me.Sheets
    sh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
Next

End Sub

Comment: @Sid Delimiter is probably not 3 dots, but `…` ie ASCII Code 133

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks for the info , it solves the issue of how vb is calculating length of the string

Comment: @JasmeetNarula the "3 dots" are in fact a _single_ character, so the length of `7…0` is 3.  The `…` character is called an [Ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp to split strings like this

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim vSplit      As Variant

    vSplit = preg_split("\D+", "1..7")
    Debug.Print vSplit(0), vSplit(1)
End Sub

Function preg_split(find_re, text)
    Dim esc             As String
    Dim re              As Object
    Dim idx             As Long

    esc = ChrW(&HE1B6) '-- U+E000 to U+F8FF - Private Use Area (PUA)
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        If Left$(find_re, 1) = "/" Then
            idx = InStrRev(find_re, "/")
            .Pattern = Mid$(find_re, 2, idx - 2)
            .IgnoreCase = (InStr(idx, find_re, "i") > 0)
            .MultiLine = (InStr(idx, find_re, "m") > 0)
        Else
            .Pattern = find_re
        End If
    End With
    preg_split = Split(re.Replace(text, esc), esc)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @wqw but i did not want to use RegExp. Somehow i found the solution of my problem , you can take a look.